# Javascript using Jquery! looping and printing value

Tags: javascript, jquery

Suppose I have this:

```
<div id="apple" class="fruit"></div>
<div id="orange" class="fruit"></div>
<div id="grape" class="fruit"></div>
<div id="pear" class="fruit"></div>
```

How do I write a javascript function that can loop and print out all the fruit IDs with class "fruit"? Using JQuery.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$('div.fruit').each(function(){
 //will loop through all divs with the class fruit.
 $(this).attr('id'); //will give you the id of the current div
});
```

Comment: and within that function, this.attr("id")

Comment: this.attr('id') is incorrect, you need $(this).attr('id'); `this.id` will work as from the documentation "`this` == domElement". The `each()` callback will allow you to use two arguments, the first being the index in the result list, the second again being the dom element.

Comment: @Colin - yes, `this.id` would work too and would probably be more optimal since `this` is not being wrapped in a jQuery object inside each iteration

Answer (score 2):

As printed out as comma separated list (ids is an array of the ids).

```
var ids = $.map($('div.fruit'), function(e) {
    return e.id;
});
document.write(ids.join(','));
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsbin.com/evite/edit)** - click on the output tab to see the output.

Using the following would cater for there being `<div class="fruit">` with no `id`

```
var ids = $.map($('div.fruit'), function(e) {
    return e.id? e.id : null;
});
```

Comment: This is incorrect, since the callback functions first argument is the index to the element in the list, use `this.id` instead; or use a second argument to your callback function which will be the DOM element. Alternatively use `$(this).attr('id')`.

Comment: @Brett - Wrong. Have a read of the documentation http://docs.jquery.com/Utilities/jQuery.map e will be element. Try it out on http://jsbin.com

Comment: The second argument (which hasn't been given) would be the index

Comment: @Russ, how right you are, my appologies, I mistakenly read this as if it were `$('div.fruit').map(callback)`, which behaves as I mentioned (http://docs.jquery.com/Traversing/map#callback).

Comment: @Brett- no worries! Apologies if I came across terse, it's a bit of a challenge writing long replies on the iPhone :)

Comment: lol, not a problem at all :) I am actually surprised with `$.map` as most callbacks in jQuery accept the index as the first argument.